# How to add a separate scrollbar to each css grid row?

Tags: css, vue.js, overflow, css-grid

I have a calculated variable css grid, where each item has a property 'grid-row' and 'grid-column'. It is no problem to add a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom.

But I would like to scroll each row separately. How can this be achieved?

This is a component in vue project.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    contents: {
        '754637': {
            first: 'Bla Bla',
            second: 'test Test',
            third: 'some some'
        },
        '454554': {
            first: 'Bla Bla',
            second: 'test Test',
            third: 'some some'
        },
        '12121212': {
            first: 'Bla Bla',
            second: 'test Test',
            third: 'some some'
        }
      },
      rowIndex: {
        '754637': 2,
        '454554': 3,
        '12121212': 4
      }
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 100%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container" id="comparison-table-container">
    <div :style="{ 'grid-row': 1, 'grid-column': 1, 'width':'1000px'}">
        Title 1
    </div>
    <div :style="{ 'grid-row': 1, 'grid-column': 2, 'width':'1000px' }">
        Title 2
    </div>
    <div :style="{ 'grid-row': 1, 'grid-column': 3, 'width':'1000px' }">
        Title 3
    </div>
 
    <template v-for="(content, key) in contents"  >
        <div :key="1+key" :style="{ 'grid-row': rowIndex[key], 'grid-column': '1' }">
            {{content.first}}
        </div>
        <div :key="2+key" :style="{ 'grid-row': rowIndex[key], 'grid-column': '2' }">
            {{content.second}}
        </div>
        <div :key="3+key" :style="{ 'grid-row': rowIndex[key], 'grid-column': '3' }">
            {{content.third}}
        </div>
    </template>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show a simple example? Particularly how you are using grid-row and grid-column. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It sounds like you created your own layout and are not actually using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids), which makes it even more important to see the structure you are using. Please take the time to look through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the section "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: There are no such elements as grid rows or columns and so they cannot have scrollbars. They are positional information and not like, for instance, table rows.

Comment: I added a simple codesnippet

Comment: You cannot scroll individual rows in CSS Grid as that would break the columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you make each row a separate grid, you’ll be able to scroll them individually. But then it doesn’t really make sense having column titles in the first row, because they won’t scroll across with the data.

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  margin: 1em;
}
.container {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.container>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1000px);
  gap: 1em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="comparison-table-container">

  <div>
    <div>Title 1</div>
    <div>Title 2</div>
    <div>Title 3</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>Bla Bla</div>
    <div>test Test</div>
    <div>some some</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>Bla Bla</div>
    <div>test Test</div>
    <div>some some</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>Bla Bla</div>
    <div>test Test</div>
    <div>some some</div>
  </div>

</div>
```